# What type of fig to plant in the Netherlands

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, plant-recommendations, figs

I have a garden that I would like to grow a fig tree in, currently it already has a fig, however the fig in question doesn't make a lot of fruit and we would like to get a 2nd one that does make a lot of fruit.

The soil is mostly made out of marine clay, though obviously soil improvement is an option(and there is a drainage circle in place), temperature in winter can get a little bit low (-10C at the lowest) with summer temperatures being as high as 35C(though most of the year it's between 10-25C). The general climate is also quite wet. I would like the fig tree to be an actual tree (not a bush, but with something of a stem) going up around 3-4 meters and bearing considerable amounts of fruit.

Do you guys think that's feasable and what type of fig tree would be best suited for this? Or would a grafting setup be best?

Comment: What kind of fig do you have already? Does it get enough sunlight? My neighbors, in Amsterdam that is, have a small fig tree. It sticks about almost a meter above the fence and is full of (green unripe) figs already this time of the year. So the tree must be between 2 and 3 meters in length. They have a common fig (*Ficus carica*), you can find a specimen in most garden centers. I doubt, however, if my neighbors ever eat those figs. They will turn up purple at the end of the year, but I am not sure if they are sweet enough for consumption.

Comment: @benn I'm not entirely certain on the type of fig as it was a rescue from a construction site.

Comment: I tried to answer your question: I think it is feasible to grow Figs here in the Netherlands, since I see them here often in Amsterdam. However I have doubt if the fruit is very sweet, you'll have to try and find out yourself. My answer was deleted and degraded to comment by the moderator (he never explains why), so I will keep my mouth shut in this tread for now. Hope someone else can help you with this! Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Ficus carica ‘Brown Turkey’. The best winter resistant variety for our Dutch climate.